# OLEDB connection in R

Tags: r, oledb

Does anyone know of any way to connect to an OLEDB data source directly in R?

I've tried google, CRAN and rseek with no luck whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative to both ODBC and OLEDB for saving data to SQL Server is to BCP using the rsqlserver package that is on GitHub here: https://github.com/agstudy/rsqlserver

You can pull down data via ODBC if you'd like which would be pretty fast, but sending data to SQL Server via ODBC will take a long time (in my tests), so BCP is a great option.

It's a little difficult to install (requires .NET and rtools), but once you get it going it's blazing fast.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on versions and drivers, this may work:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html

Comment: I don't think this is going to help. Unfortunately RODBC seems to connect only to data sources using ODBC type drivers, not OLEDB type drivers.